# How can i use Parameter Mapping in Execute SQL Task in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I am trying to  retrieve the value of `Key` from a table with a simple select statement in SSIS through `Execute SQL Task`. But have no luck figuring out this error.

I have used one input variable with string data type and used this variable in parameter mapping in `Execute SQL Task`.

> Executing the query "SELECT cast([Key] as Int) FROM   Table where
>   column = ?" failed with the following error: "An error occurred while
>   extracting the result into a variable of type (DBTYPE_I4)". Possible
>   failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set
>   correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established
>   correctly.

Note : Datatype for `Key` column is `tinyint`

Answer (score 13):

This message occurs when the default datatype for the parameters remains as 'LONG' instead of whatever is necessary... In your case, this should be 'BYTE'

[image: parameter mapping]

Answer (score 2):

Tinyint is not i4, it's [DT_UI1](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2006/02/24/SSIS-data-flows-and-tinyint.aspx). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345165.aspx

If you change your SSIS type to byte then you should be able to assign the results of your query to the value.

```
Variable User::input  Data Type Byte  Value 2
Variable User::output Data Type Byte  Value 0
```

Source query `SELECT CAST(1 AS tinyint) AS [key], ? AS foo`

Execute SQL Task, OLE DB CM, single row result set
Parameter mapping tab

- Variable Name: User::input
- Data Type:  Byte
- Parameter name:  0

Result of column 1 mapped to User::output

Inspect value after Execute SQL Task and result is 2 (expected)

Answer (score 2):

Write the query like -> SELECT cast([Key] as Int) as Key FROM Table where column = ?