# delete query in ssis package with 2 or more parameters in execute SQl Task

Tags: asp.net, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I am new to SSIS I want to execute delete query in my SSIS package thorough Execute Sql Task having 2 or more parameters. If I use 1 parameter it's working fine but if more than 1 than error. I don't want to use SP's and please help me as I am stuck from a long time.

**General**

```
TimeOut = 0
Typeconversionmode - Allowed
Result Set - None
ConnectonType - OLE DB
Connection = MyConnection
SqlSource = DirectInput
SqlStatment="delete from  tblStgPaymentProcessingACH where id=? and paymentid=?"
```

BypassPrepare = True

**Variables**

1. Name = ID , Scope = MyJOB, DataType=int64, Value=2
2. Name = PMTID , Scope = MyJOB, DataType=int64, Value=101161419602

**Parameter Mapping**

1. User::ID, Direction = input, datatype = LONG, ParameterName = 0, ParamtereSize = 0
2. User::PMTID, Direction = input, datatype = LONG, ParameterName = 1, ParamtereSize = 0

**Database DataTypes**
Column
ID - INT
Paymentid - Bigint

**Getting Error**

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "delete from  mytable
>   where id=..." failed with the following error: "An error occurred while extracting the result into a variable of type (DBTYPE_I4)". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Comment: I've never used datatype=short in an execute SQL parameter mapping. Try `LONG` instead. Also try `int64` rather than `int32` Are the columns `ID` and `PaymentId` Integers in the database?

Comment: This may be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091583/execute-sql-task-error-in-ssis You basically need to be absolultey certain about the datatypes in the database, the datatype of the SSIS variable and the datatype defined in parameter mapping. Please edit your question and add the database datatypes of those two fields

Comment: Lastly.... I assume you have ResultSet set to "No Result"? Please edit question and clarify

Comment: You could dynamically build a variable with your SQL statement in it using Expressions.  Then in the Execute SQL task execute the variable (that will have the values you are trying to use in it)

Comment: What are the datatypes of the columns in your where clause?   What are the datatypes of the SSIS variables you are mapping to the parameters?

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid - I updated all the things you said in question. I used datatype int64 and long and database datatype for these two columns are int32,int64. Resultset = none. But after all this same error.

Comment: @TabAlleman I updated all things in question. I used datatype int64 and long and database datatype for these two columns are int32,int64. Resultset = none. But after all this same error.

Comment: @Brad - I am new to ssis can you please provide some example of this - **"dynamically build a variable with your SQL statement in it using Expressions""**

Comment: Here is a link to a tutorial for setting up variables with expressions.  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4564/ssis-variable-and-expression-example--part-1/

Comment: Can you isolate the error down to the `id` or `paymentid` variable field? That is the obvious next step - remove components till it works so you can narrow it down to a particular component